# How to use 'INSERT INTO' command with after update trigger on same table?

Tags: mysql, database, triggers

I want to use INSERT INTO command with after update trigger on the same table.

I am creating the trigger as follows.

[image]

But when I make -1 the status from 0 in xx_transactions table, I get **'Can't update table 'xx_transactions' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.'** error. How can I fix this situation? I just want to insert on the same table with trigger.

Comment: I just want to insert on the same table with trigger. -  you cannot. Please amend your question to describe what you are trying to do, include sample data and expected outcome.

Comment: I hope you understand what I am trying to do in the insert code. When the update trigger runs on the same table, I just want to add a different row to the same table. What is the reason why this is not possible?

Comment: What is the reason why this is not possible?  Insert invokes trigger which inserts which invokes trigger which inserts which invokes trigger...etc mysql just says no to avoid this possibility irrespective of whether the insert may or may not occur,,

Comment: Okay i understand that but is there any alternative way?